# Copy data to another selected sheet using Command Button

Tags: excel, vba

Sir, I have a problem in excell.
I have a file in excell consist of several sheet.
In sheet "Student", there is a list name of students in range of cells (b2:b21) and also a list of their subject in range (d2:d5).

In sheet "Form", there are form to input result of their test in range (D7:M7), a cell for name of student (D2) and a cell for their subject (D4). (D2) and (D4) is a drop down list and source from "Student" sheet.

I also created several subject sheets

I want to copy data from "Form" sheet range (D7:M7) to "Math" sheet or "Physic" sheet or etc range (C4:L23), depend on what is selected in cell (D2) and (D4).
I also add activex control command button "Submit". So, when I klik "Submit" button, data in "Form" sheet range (D7:M7), copied to another sheet in range (C4:L23).
I need vba code to program "Submit" command button in order to make the proces done.

Answer (score 0):

I assuming this is the "Form" worksheet look like
[image: Form worksheet]

 and the "subject" worksheet look like the following:
[image: subject worksheet]

 when the button is click , the result is copied to the corresponding subject worksheet: 
[image: Result copied] 
The following is the source code for the button:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ResultWorkbook As Workbook
Dim FormWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim SubjectWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim ListRange As Range

Sub CopyResult()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurrentRow As Long

Set ResultWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set FormWorksheet = ResultWorkbook.Sheets("Form")
Set SubjectWorksheet = ResultWorkbook.Sheets(FormWorksheet.Range("D4").Value)
Set ListRange = FormWorksheet.Range("D7:M7")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = SubjectWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 4 To LastRow
    If SubjectWorksheet.Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value = FormWorksheet.Range("D2").Value Then
        SubjectWorksheet.Range("C" & CurrentRow & ":L" & CurrentRow).Value = ListRange.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```